# Reactjs: How to perform edit action and open modal according to its respective id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, modal-dialog

I want to handle `Edit/update` action on my modal value of my blog.

**All the actions ADD, EDIT, DELETE are working now**

**Only issue is on click every edit I am getting same blog data of 0th array**

any suggestion on this. How can i handle this and open modal with respective to its id only ?

Thanks

//Blog.js

```
<Grid style={{padding: 0}} id="todo">
    {activeBlogs.map((item, index) => (
        <Cell key={item._id} data-id={item._id}>   
            <Card shadow={5} className="cards-grid">


                {item.blog_image_link ?
                    (<CardTitle style={{color: '#fff', height: '200px',
                    width: 'auto', backgroundImage: `url(${item.blog_image_link})`, backgroundPosition: 'center',
                    backgroundSize: 'cover',
                    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat'}}></CardTitle>) :

                    (<CardTitle className="card-title-image"></CardTitle>
                    )
                }

                <CardText>
                    <b>{item.blog_short_desc}</b>
                </CardText>

                <CardActions border>
                    <p>
                    <Button className="blog-read-me-button col-4" onClick={this.handleOpenDialog.bind(this, item._id)}>Read </Button> 

                    { isAuthenticated && (item.blog_by === user._id) ? 
                    <span className="col=8">

                    <Button className="remove-btn-blog-post"
                    color="danger"
                    size="sm"
                    onClick= {this.onDeleteBlogClick.bind(this, item._id)} title="Delete Blog">
                        &times;
                    </Button> 

                    <EditBlog  onClick={() => this.replaceModalItem(this, item._id)} /> 
                    </span> : null }
                    </p>

                    <p style={{ fontStyle:'italic', fontWeight:'bold'}}>By-{item.blog_by_author} <span style={{float:'right',}}>{Moment(item.date).format('Do MMMM YYYY')}</span></p> 
                </CardActions>
            </Card>  
        </Cell>  
    ))} 
</Grid>
```

//Edit.js (child component)

```
class EditBlog extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
            this.state = {
                modal: false,
                requiredItem : null,
                _id: '',
                blog_short_desc: '',
                blog_name: '',
                blog_desc: '',
                blog_image_link: '',
                blog_by: '',
                blog_by_author: ''
            };
            this.replaceModalItem = this.replaceModalItem.bind(this);
            this.onTodoChange = this.onTodoChange.bind(this);

        }

    static propTypes = {
        auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        updateBlog: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        editBlog: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        resume: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    }

    UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({
            value: nextProps.name
        })
    }
    toggle = (id) => {
        this.setState({
            modal: !this.state.modal
        });
    }
    componentWillMount() {

        this.props.resume["blogs"].map((blog) => {
            this.setState({
                updatable : false,
                _id: blog._id,
                blog_short_desc: blog.blog_short_desc,
                blog_name: blog.blog_name,
                blog_desc: blog.blog_desc,
                blog_image_link: blog.blog_image_link,
                blog_by: blog.blog_by,
                blog_by_author: blog.blog_by_author
            });

        })


        debugger
    }

    // replaceModalItem(id) {
    //     debugger
    //     this.setState({
    //         requiredItem : id
    //     })
    // }

    replaceModalItem(id) {
        this.setState({
          openDialog: true,
          OpenEditDialog: true,
          requiredItem: id

        });
    }

    // titleHandler(e) {
    //     this.setState({ [e.target.name] : e.target.value });
    // }

    onTodoChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({ 
            [e.target.name] : e.target.value 
        });
    }

    onSubmit = (e, id) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const updatedBlog = {
            blog_short_desc: this.state.blog_short_desc,
            blog_name: this.state.blog_name,
            blog_desc: this.state.blog_desc,
            blog_image_link: this.state.blog_image_link,
            blog_by:  this.props.auth["user"]._id,
            blog_by_author: this.props.auth["user"].name
        }
        //update blog via updateblog action
        this.props.updateBlog(id, updatedBlog, this.props.history);
        alert("Blog updated successfully!");

        debugger
        //close modal
        e.target.reset();
        this.toggle();
    }


    render(){

        return(
            <span>

                <a className="btn edit-btn-blog-post" href="#" onClick={this.toggle} title="Edit Blog">
                    <i className="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
                <Modal 
                    isOpen = {this.state.modal}
                    toggle = {this.toggle}    
                ></Modal>

                <Modal 
                    isOpen = {this.state.modal}
                    toggle = {this.toggle}    
                >
                    <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle} style={{fontWeight: "bold"}}>
                        Edit your blog {this.state.blog_name}
                    </ModalHeader>
                    <ModalBody>
                        <Form onSubmit={e => this.onSubmit(e, this.state._id, )}>
                            <FormGroup>
                                <Label for="blogHeading">Blog Heading</Label>
                                <Input type="text" name="blog_short_desc" id="blogHeading" placeholder="Update one liner"
                                onChange={this.onTodoChange} value={this.state.blog_short_desc}/>
                                 <Label for="blogName">Blog Name</Label>
                                <Input type="text" name="blog_name" id="blogName" placeholder="Update blog name"
                                onChange={this.onTodoChange} value={this.state.blog_name}/>
                                <Label for="desc1">Description </Label>
                                <Input type="textarea" name="blog_desc" id="desc1" placeholder="Update your blog"
                                onChange={this.onTodoChange} value={this.state.blog_desc}/>
                                 <Label for="imageUrl">Image Url</Label>
                                <Input type="text" name="blog_image_link" id="imageUrl" placeholder="Update image url (Optional)"
                                onChange={this.onTodoChange} value={this.state.blog_image_link}/>
                                <Button
                                    color="dark"
                                    style={{marginTop: '2rem'}}
                                    block
                                >Edit blog</Button>
                            </FormGroup>
                        </Form>
                    </ModalBody>
                </Modal>
            </span>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    resume: state.resume,
    auth: state.auth
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { updateBlog })(EditBlog);
```

//blog UI

[image]

Comment: Instead of using `modal: boolean` you could use your `prefilled value` whatever that is.

Comment: Hi Wederer . Thanks for your precious time. Could you please suggest with my current code how can I do so.

Comment: I have updated my code. Now I can able to fetch the data into my modal but  I am unable to edit this data.

Comment: What might be the issue here for not able to keep non edited input data? Any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Get your record data in `componentDidMount` and then use `setState` to populate your form.

Comment: Hi Zain, Thanks but could you please elabaorate it a  further. Not much familiar with redux reducer  and edit action.

Comment: In Edit form component, use componentDidMount lifecycle method and  make a GET request with id of record to backend in that and use that response to pre populate form fields

Comment: This won't work here as on page load it would call `componentDidMount` whereas my data will only availbale when user press edit and modal opens.